# How do I install Pygame on Windows8 to work with Python 3.3.3?

Tags: python, windows, windows-8, pygame, python-3.3

Speaking as someone who is new to stackoverflow and not that computer literate...

How do I get Pygame to work? I have been using IDLE (python GUI), Python version 3.3.3, and I want to add on Pygame. I downloaded and installed "pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_56e0eadfc267.win32-py3.3.msi" from Bitbucket and then tried to "import pygame" but got the following output in my window:

> Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600
>   64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>
> import pygame Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> import pygame
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python333\lib\site-packages\pygame__init__.py", line 127, in
>    from pygame.base import *
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Does anyone know what is wrong, and how I can fix it?

Many thanks

L.

Comment: It looks like you installed the 32-bit version of pygame when your Python version is 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Direct quote from the site

> windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.

Also an extension to @Marius 's comment, you can get a pre-release 64 bit version of pygame here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame